# Is there a way to set the icon of wx.ProgressDialog?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to set icon for wx.ProgressDialog in my app built using wxPython. The SetIcon() method somehow do not work and it always comes-up with default icon. Here is my sample code:

```
dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Progress dialog example",
                           "An informative message",
                           maximum = max,
                           parent=self,
                           style = wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
                            | wx.PD_APP_MODAL
                            | wx.PD_ELAPSED_TIME
                            | wx.PD_REMAINING_TIME
                            )

dlg.SetIcon(wx.IconFromBitmap(icon_dialog.GetImage().ConvertToBitmap()))
```

Any help would be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

heh, I am looking for an answer to this myself.  It appears that the built in wx.Dialog.SetIcon method does not work.